# How to change text under an image when the image is clicked/hovered on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a page for a company where they have pictures of the 4 founders all side by side. The text under all 4 images needs to change based on what photo is clicked or hovered on. So one says "mark" in bold and under that it will have his qualifications. But that will all be replaced when I click "kim" who is the next picture.
I'm very new to HTML, CSS, and have never tried javascript so this is my first attempt.

I want the text to be styled the way I want, but I can't find a way to update it all. I only figured out that I can print raw text. 
Is there a way to call a div to put the text there and replace it with a new div for each image click?

Like instead of writing .html("Mark does xyz") you could instead paste in the entire div "tr1" with the changed button and heading and paragraph?

```
<div id="trainers">
        <h1><b>Meet Our Trainers</h1>
        <img src="jackf.jpg" id="Mark" alt="Mark" width="17%" height="40%">
        <img src="kimsond.jpg" id="Kim" alt="Kim" width="17%" height="40%">


<div id="tr1">
  <h1><b><br>Mark</b></h1>
  <p>Mark has been a personal trainer</p>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Book With Mark</a>
</div>
<div id="tr2">
  <h1><b><br>Kim</b></h1>
  <p>Kim is a nutritionist</p>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Book With Kim</a>
</div>
</div>






<script>
    $('#Mark').click(function() {
    });

    $('#Kim').click(function() {
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use show/hide method for your requirement.

```
$('#Mark').click(function() {
   $('#tr1').show();
   $('#tr2').hide();
});

$('#Kim').click(function() {
   $('#tr1').hide();
   $('#tr2').show();
});
```

```js
$('#Mark').click(function() {
       $('#tr1').show();
       $('#tr2').hide();
    });

    $('#Kim').click(function() {
       $('#tr1').hide();
       $('#tr2').show();
    });
```

```css
#tr2{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="trainers">
        <h1><b>Meet Our Trainers</h1>
        <img src="jackf.jpg" id="Mark" alt="Mark" width="17%" height="40%">
        <img src="kimsond.jpg" id="Kim" alt="Kim" width="17%" height="40%">


<div id="tr1">
  <h1><b><br>Mark</b></h1>
  <p>Mark has been a personal trainer</p>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Book With Mark</a>
</div>
<div id="tr2">
  <h1><b><br>Kim</b></h1>
  <p>Kim is a nutritionist</p>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Book With Kim</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works really well! Just one thing, it seems that by default none will show up. Is there a way to make "tr1" be the only one that shows up automatically when the page is loaded?

Comment: I updated the answer, only #tr2 display at page loaded

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Mark').click(function() {
    var elementToClone = document.getElementById('tr1');
    var clone = elementToClone.cloneNode(true);
    var container = document.getElementById('container');

    // Then you need to append that cloned element into a container on the page.

    container.appendChild(clone);       
});
```

The container will be en element in your HTML that currently is not there. This is just a place where you want this cloned HTML to go:

```
<div id="container></div>
```

This will get you to a point where you've copied the HTML you need and placed it where you want it on the page. When you click a different image, you'll need to remove this HTML, clone the *other* HTML and append it to `container`. You'll also probably need an `if` statement in there to check if `container` contains something already.

You're using jQuery in your question, so this answer uses the jQuery `click` function -- if you don't have jQuery included, you'll need it.

You can also use these vanilla js click methods:

```
<img id="Mark" onclick="doHTMLAppendFunction()" src="foo.jpg" />
```

or

```
document.getElementById('Mark').addEventListener('click', doHTMLAppendFunction);
```

Comment: Note that this answer requires the inclusion of JQuery.

Comment: The original poster set up their click methods with jQuery. I wouldn't personally do this with jQuery, but that's how they have it set up.

Comment: I don't have to do it with jQuery, I just had it set up like that from some tutorials I watched. What do you recommend to use instead? Thanks.

Comment: Adding some vanilla js things in my answer

Comment: vanilla js just means that it's javascript without any libraries like jQuery. If you are learning javascript, the best thing to do is learn vanilla javascript first, but a lot of people feel that jQuery is easier and is shorter to type..so if you don't intend on learning javascript very well, jQuery is a pretty great resource to start with! This solution is a mix of jQuery and vanilla js, but a solution like @Hien Nguyen provided is a good all-jQuery solution

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use JQuery to achieve this and following does the job. There used the common class "trainer-text" to hide all overlay texts to hide at the initial point. Use some css to make the text on your images. Refer the following to achieve that. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp

```js
/*
    Use the following if you need display text for hover event
*/
$("#Mark").mouseover(function(){
    $("#tr1").css("display", "block");
});
$("#Mark").mouseout(function(){
    $("#tr1").css("display", "none");
});
$("#Kim").mouseover(function(){
    $("#tr2").css("display", "block");
});
$("#Kim").mouseout(function(){
    $("#tr2").css("display", "none");
});

/*
    Use the following if you need display text for click event
*/
$('#Mark').click(function() {
    $('#tr1').show();
    $('#tr2').hide();
});

$('#Kim').click(function() {
    $('#tr1').hide();
    $('#tr2').show();
});
```

```css
.trainer-text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="trainers">
    <h1><b>Meet Our Trainers</b></h1>
    <img src="jackf.jpg" id="Mark" alt="Mark" width="17%" height="40%"/>
    <img src="kimsond.jpg" id="Kim" alt="Kim" width="17%" height="40%"/>

    <div id="tr1" class="trainer-text">
        <h1><b><br>Mark</b></h1>
        <p>Mark has been a personal trainer</p>
        <a class="btn" href="#">Book With Mark</a>
    </div>
    <div id="tr2" class="trainer-text">
        <h1><b><br>Kim</b></h1>
        <p>Kim is a nutritionist</p>
        <a class="btn" href="#">Book With Kim</a>
    </div>
</div>
```